# error for public stream in Twitter 4j in IBM WAS 6.1

Tags: websphere

I'm getting below error for public stream using Twitter 4j in IBM WAS 6.1.Can you please suggest on this issue .

INFO: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found
    com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found
    Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=944a924a or
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=24fd66eb
    TwitterException{exceptionCode=[944a924a-24fd66eb 944a924a-24fd66c1 944a924a-24fd66c1], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:192)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
        at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getFilterStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:304)
        at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$7.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:292)
        at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:462)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found
        at com.ibm.jsse2.n.a(n.java:28)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.jc.a(jc.java:235)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.db.a(db.java:268)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.db.a(db.java:272)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.eb.a(eb.java:56)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.eb.a(eb.java:122)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.db.m(db.java:351)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.db.a(db.java:173)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.jc.a(jc.java:535)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.jc.g(jc.java:203)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.jc.a(jc.java:97)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.jc.startHandshake(jc.java:44)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.afterConnect(b.java:38)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.connect(c.java:34)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:866)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.a.getOutputStream(a.java:38)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:150)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:24)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.b(g.java:54)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:9)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yb.checkServerTrusted(yb.java:4)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.checkServerTrusted(hb.java:9)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.eb.a(eb.java:193)
        ... 17 more
    Jul 3, 2013 10:14:56 AM twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLogger info
    INFO: Waiting for 500 milliseconds
    Jul 3, 2013 10:14:56 AM twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLogger info
    INFO: Establishing connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is now resolved by adding SSL certificate in JVM. [This page](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html) really helped me to understand SSL connection concept in Java.